# ng serve error localhost could NOT be bound

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

I am new in angular 5, I am try to run angular 5 project get following error
    "ng serve error localhost could NOT be bound". any one can help me.

```
example:

D:\workspace\newapp>ng serve

Provided host localhost could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname
Error: Provided host localhost could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname`enter code here`
    at D:\workspace\newapp\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinder.js:139:27
    at D:\workspace\newapp\node_modules\portfinder\node_modules\async\lib\async.
js:52:16
    at D:\workspace\newapp\node_modules\portfinder\node_modules\async\lib\async.
js:264:21
    at D:\workspace\newapp\node_modules\portfinder\node_modules\async\lib\async.
js:44:16
    at D:\workspace\newapp\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinder.js:117:16
    at Server.onError (D:\workspace\newapp\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinde
r.js:54:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1387:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: Do you have a localhost mapping in your `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file?

Answer (score 3):

Use this command in the Visual tutorial terminal/cmd prmt.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution

```
example:

D:\workspace\newapp>ng serve --host 192.168.43.131 --port 4200
```

Comment: Not working with ng(7.3.9). ng serve --host test.local --port 4200