# It's my first time creating Angular project through Git Bash and it Shows

Tags: javascript, angular

a4app is the name of the project I want to create so this is what shows up in gitbash but it takes like 10 mins to finish and it shows error so the time that it takes and the error or the odd messages that it shows. I think it has a problem. I never used the app that I created yet until someone tell me why it has that kind of message because its very odd.

```
$ ng new a4app
CREATE a4app/angular.json (3539 bytes)
CREATE a4app/package.json (1309 bytes)
CREATE a4app/README.md (1022 bytes)
CREATE a4app/tsconfig.json (384 bytes)
CREATE a4app/tslint.json (2805 bytes)
CREATE a4app/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE a4app/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/environments/environment.ts (631 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/index.html (292 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/polyfills.ts (3194 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/browserslist (375 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/tsconfig.app.json (194 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/tsconfig.spec.json (282 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (988 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
CREATE a4app/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE a4app/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE a4app/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (301 bytes)
CREATE a4app/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE a4app/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump

> node-sass@4.9.0 install C:\Users\bords\Projects\Angular\a4app\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Download complete
Binary saved to C:\Users\bords\Projects\Angular\a4app\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
Caching binary to C:\Users\bords\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.9.0\win32-x64-57_binding.node

> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall C:\Users\bords\Projects\Angular\a4app\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\Users\bords\Projects\Angular\a4app\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall C:\Users\bords\Projects\Angular\a4app\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1114 packages in 380.081s
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .editorconfig.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in angular.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/protractor.conf.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/src/app.po.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package-lock.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.spec.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.component.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/app/app.module.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/browserslist.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/environments/environment.prod.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/environments/environment.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/index.html.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/karma.conf.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/main.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/polyfills.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/styles.css.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/test.ts.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/tsconfig.app.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/tsconfig.spec.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/tslint.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tsconfig.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in tslint.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
Successfully initialized git.
```

So thank you so much guys in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install [Angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) and follow instructions provided on site of this project. Installation may take some time, if your internet is slow.

I don't see errors in your listing, maybe you can go to angular app project and just run "ng serve". This should start your app on localhost:4200

Comment: So how about the messages or all the warnings? is it normal?

Comment: So I should just ignore all the warnings?

Comment: Just try to run this using ng serve

Comment: $ ng serve
Provided host localhost could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname
Error: Provided host localhost could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname
    at C:\Users\bords\Projects\Angular\a4app\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinder.js:139:27
    at  /* IT SAYS SOMETHING LIKE THAT */ and It shows nothing in localhost:4200

Comment: Kill all node processes in Task Manager and retry. You can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49222319/ng-serve-error-localhost-could-not-be-bound